# ASP.Net WebAPI and logging with Serilog

Tags: asp.net-web-api, serilog

I want to use Serilog in my WebApi project in order to log user actions, and exceptions. All the logs would be push in ElasticSearch.

I also want to log from some custom library dependencies.

In order to not have different references of serilog in my dependencies and my webApi project, I have been told that the better way is to use *microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions* and inject the logger in the dependencies.

In my understanding, the problem is that if I do it this way I could not anymore use all the power of Serilog and I would have to constrain myself with what is offered by the abstraction... For instance, I want also to have some custom extension like :

```
  logger.LogBusiness({msg}
  logger.LogPerformance({msg})
  logger.LogTechnical({msg})
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want :

1. use the Microsoft.extension.Logging.Abstractions in my WebApi
2. have the possibility to push my logs to elasticksearch with serilog
3. inject a Ilogger abstraction in my dependencies so they are not
   dependent on a specific version of serilog
4. use some custom extension on the ilogger in order to push my logs in different elasticSearch indexes (one for businness event, one for performance event..).